# How to enable global save functionality in Eclipse RCP plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have an RCP application based on the 3.x platform. The application enables the user to view and modify a single data set. Some `ViewParts` are only observers of part of the data set, whilst other can modify data. When a `ViewPart` modifies same data I want to be able to save the data set, preferably using the standard `org.eclipse.ui.file.save` command, independent of which `ViewPart` that currently has focus.

My approach is to define extensions to the `plugin.xml` like so:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
            allPopups="false"
            locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar">
         <toolbar
               id="se.file.maintoolbar"
               label="File Toolbar">
            <command
                  commandId="org.eclipse.ui.file.save"
                  label="&amp;Save Project"
                  style="push"
                  tooltip="Save the project">
            </command>
         </toolbar>
      </menuContribution>
   </extension>
.
.
.
</plugin>
```

In my implementation of `ActionBarAdvisor` I register actions:

```java
@Override
protected void makeActions(IWorkbenchWindow window) {
    saveProjectAction = ActionFactory.SAVE.create(window);
    register(saveProjectAction);
}
```

My `ViewParts`, three kinds, all implements the `ISaveablePart2`, it feels wrong, but haven't seen any other approach. Two of the views control their `isDirty()` function, so save buttons are enabled when they have focus and if they are dirty, but if one of them is dirty, save should be enabled in all views, not just the dirty view. Enabling save functionality for the third view, without indicating dirty, seems impossible.

Anybody know a better approach? I guess I can create my own handling of saving, but would be good to use standard as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You could call `firePropertyChange(IWorkbenchPartConstants.PROP_DIRTY)` in all the views that should be shown as dirty.

Comment: Yes, I do that in the views that should be shown as dirty and that enables the save command for that view, but not the other views, which are not dirty, but should be able to save the modifications in the views that are dirty.

Comment: If you want to stay with `ISaveablePart2` you will have to make every view report it is dirty

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yes, I might have to go about it that way, I'd rather make the whole application into a some sort of saveable, do you know if that's possible?

Comment: I don't think so, the saveables code is very much oriented to the workbench parts. There is also `ISaveablesSource` and `Saveable` but this gives multiple saveables per part rather than one per workbench.

Comment: Ok, thanks man, I'll leave it open to explore other possibilities. Looking through the code how the framework gets the saveables, it seems possible to register adapters per `ViewPart` (via `Platform.getAdapterManager().registerAdapter()`), but I guess it would only give the same functionality as setting dirty flag on all views, with the benefit of only having to code the saveable once.